# Return The Lowest Factor

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm kind of struggling on this homework question

**Define the method below to return the lowest factor of an arbitrary integer. The lowest factor is the smallest number greater than 1 that will divide evenly into the parameter (which will be 2 or higher)**

this is as far as I've gotten.

```
def first_factor(n):
    for num in range(1,n):
        if n % num == 0:
            return n
```

So I get this will only return Prime numbers how do I return the lowest number?
Thank you

Comment: You need to return `num`

Comment: Shouldn't the range start at 2?

Comment: that still doesnt work

Comment: okay changing the range worked thank you!

Answer (score 2):

return `num` instead of `n` also iterate only until `sqrt(n)` (inclusive), if there are no factors smaller or equal to `sqrt(n)` then the number is prime.

Comment: Also start iterating `num` from 2.